# Why Laravel Echo not listening

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a small chat project, but it seems like Laravel echo is not listening, since I can see the log (message) correctly on pusher website dashboard

this is my code :

```
mounted: function(){
        
        Echo.private('chat').listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
            console.log(e)
            
        });
    },
```

This is my `bootstrap.js` file

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true
});


my channel.php


Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    return auth()->check();
});
```

By the way I see the messages on pusher dashboard, but my vue application is not listening

I'm getting in the console:

```
No callbacks on private-chat
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `.` before event name

Chang this

```
mounted: function(){
        
        Echo.private('chat').listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
            console.log(e)
            
        });
    },
```

to this

```
mounted: function(){
        
        Echo.private('chat').listen('.MessageSent', (e) => {
            console.log(e)
            
        });
    },
```